# Scope issue with xmlhttprequest and Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm new to JS and I've been toying around trying to implement a sort of sound mixer with the Web Audio API. I have been reading a bit about the scope on JS and different ways to implement "classes", but obviously I don't quite understand it yet.
I have this `soundClass` object which I'd like it to contain an array of `track` objects and I'd like to `push` a new `track` on the `tracklist` as soon as it's decoded. However, whenever I `console.log` the `tracklist` or each `track` as it's shown below, the first log (`console.log('track name '+ that.track.name);`) shows the correct track name, but if I try and log the `that.track` object itself it always shows the last track added, so if I call `soundClass.newTrack('track1.mp3')` and `soundClass.newTrack('track2.mp3')` and `console.log(soundClass.tracklist)` I get an array with two track2.mp3 objects.
I suppose it's a scope issue or a problem with the asynchronous decoding, but I have actually no idea, so it might just be some stupid mistake.

I'm sorry if this is a really basic question but I'd appreciate any help.

```
var soundClass = {

audioContext: new webkitAudioContext,
currentTime: 0,
track: {
    name: 0,
    trackSource: null,
    trackBuffer:null,
    isLoaded: false,
},
tracklist: [],
newTrack: function(filename){
    var that=this;      
    var request =new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET",filename,true);
    request.responseType="arraybuffer";
    request.onload=function(){
            that.audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response,function(buffer){

                that.track.trackBuffer=buffer;
                that.track.name=filename;
                that.track.isLoaded=true;
                that.track.trackSource=that.audioContext.createBufferSource();

                console.log('track name '+ that.track.name);
                console.log(that.track);

                that.tracklist.push(that.track);

                });

    }
    request.send();
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one object `soundclass.track`. Within the `request.onload` function you are modifying the same object again and again. So your `tracklist` contains the same object twice. What you can do is

```
var track = {};
track.trackBuffer=buffer;
...
that.tracklist.push(track);
```

and get rid of soundclass.track.

Comment: Thank you!, it really was stupid of me to put `track` as a literal inside `soundclass`. But I'm curious anyway as to why that was happening. Even if I was overwriting `track`, I was appending it first to the `tracklist` array, so the array should be ok? anyways, thanks again!

Comment: The array's fine. Would you mind accepting the answer if it works for you? :)

Comment: But then why the log output of the tracklist was only the last object appended as many times as the newTrack was called?.

Comment: There is only one object. First you set its values to "track1.mp3" etc. and add it to the array. `tracklist[0]` points to `track` which has the value "track1.mp3". Then you change the value and add it to the array again. `tracklist[1]` now points to `track`, too,  and `track` has the value "track2.mpg". `tracklist[0]` still points to `track`, of course. And the value of `track` is ... "track2.mp3" ^^